# Problematic frame: # C [zip.dll+0xa714] (JVM crash because EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)

Tags: java, jvm

I am currently working on a java project(design a card game) and there is a method to choose the suitable card in a player's hand. But A fatal error happend irregularly (not in a fixed time). Here is the header of the log

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fffd58ba714, pid=5604, tid=0x0000000000004314
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b10) (build 1.8.0_212-b10)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [zip.dll+0xa714]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

It seems like the problem happends in native C (# C [zip.dll+0xa714]).How can I fix it? BTW, I have tried deploy a larger memory to JVM. It still happends sometime.The JDK version I am using is jdk1.8.0_212. and sometimes the error is not shown,"Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)" instead shown in terminal. I don't know whether it is the same cause.Here is the full hs_err_pid.log

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001f747000):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=17172, stack(0x0000000022ae0000,0x0000000022be0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x000000000000013c

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x000000001c7cef20, RCX=0x0000000000000007, RDX=0x000000000000004f
RSP=0x0000000022bda9d0, RBP=0x0000000022bdaed0, RSI=0x00000000d337d595, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000001, R10=0x0000000022bdaa6f, R11=0x0000000022bdaa50
R12=0x0000000022bdaa50, R13=0x000000000000001f, R14=0x000000000000001f, R15=0x000000001f747001
RIP=0x00007fffd58ba714, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000022bda9d0)
0x0000000022bda9d0:   0000000024492c58 0000000022d9fc68
0x0000000022bda9e0:   0000000093c2dd3a 000000006b2463c2
0x0000000022bda9f0:   000000001f747000 0000000022bdaef8
0x0000000022bdaa00:   00000006c42c1101 000000001c7cef20
0x0000000022bdaa10:   000000001f7471f8 00007fffd58b2023
0x0000000022bdaa20:   0000000022bdaa50 0000000022bdaed0
0x0000000022bdaa30:   000000000000001f 000000001f7471f8
0x0000000022bdaa40:   0000000022bdaa50 0000000022be1888
0x0000000022bdaa50:   2f756c70612f6863 697267656d61676a
0x0000000022bdaa60:   73756f4d47472f64 007373616c632e65
0x0000000022bdaa70:   000000001c490900 000000002448d068
0x0000000022bdaa80:   000000002448d268 00007fff1bfd42d0
0x0000000022bdaa90:   0000000022c9e740 000000002460b110
0x0000000022bdaaa0:   0000000022be4f38 000000001c520650
0x0000000022bdaab0:   0000000022c9ea60 0000000024486418
0x0000000022bdaac0:   0000000022d961a0 00000000244863d8 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007fffd58ba714)
0x00007fffd58ba6f4:   ff e8 f8 07 00 00 39 7b 60 74 4f 33 d2 8b c6 4d
0x00007fffd58ba704:   8b f5 f7 73 70 48 8b 43 68 48 8b bb 80 00 00 00
0x00007fffd58ba714:   44 8b 14 90 48 85 ff 74 5a 8b 57 44 4d 8b cc 41
0x00007fffd58ba724:   3b d5 75 4f 85 d2 7e 1a 4c 8b 07 4d 2b c4 43 8a 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000001c7cef20 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000007 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000000004f is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000022bda9d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001f747000
RBP=0x0000000022bdaed0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001f747000
RSI=0x00000000d337d595 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000022bdaa6f is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001f747000
R11=0x0000000022bdaa50 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001f747000
R12=0x0000000022bdaa50 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001f747000
R13=0x000000000000001f is an unknown value
R14=0x000000000000001f is an unknown value
R15=0x000000001f747001 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000022ae0000,0x0000000022be0000],  sp=0x0000000022bda9d0,  free space=1002k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [zip.dll+0xa714]
C  [zip.dll+0x2023]
C  0x0000000002fe8460

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 276  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(J[BZ)J (0 bytes) @ 0x0000000002fe83da [0x0000000002fe8380+0x5a]
J 990 C2 sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource; (85 bytes) @ 0x0000000003208f00 [0x0000000003208900+0x600]
J 694 C1 sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource; (83 bytes) @ 0x000000000310414c [0x0000000003103fe0+0x16c]
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Class;+26
j  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 1196  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x000000000326ba26 [0x000000000326b9c0+0x66]
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+13
J 136 C1 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class; (122 bytes) @ 0x0000000002fa05b4 [0x0000000002f9fc40+0x974]
J 695 C1 sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class; (85 bytes) @ 0x000000000310b6cc [0x000000000310ad00+0x9cc]
J 347 C1 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (7 bytes) @ 0x0000000003015f4c [0x0000000003015e40+0x10c]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  ch.aplu.jgamegrid.GameGrid$MyMouseAdapter.notifyMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;I)V+119
j  ch.aplu.jgamegrid.GameGrid$MyMouseAdapter.mousePressed(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+15
j  java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+54
j  java.awt.Component.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+81
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+589
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+41
j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+32
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 1172  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x0000000003264426 [0x00000000032643c0+0x66]
J 1711 C1 java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (22 bytes) @ 0x0000000003482cfc [0x0000000003482880+0x47c]
j  java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.awt.EventQueue$4.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+11
j  java.awt.EventQueue$4.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 1172  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x0000000003264426 [0x00000000032643c0+0x66]
J 1724 C1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (80 bytes) @ 0x000000000348aafc [0x0000000003489c40+0xebc]
J 1727 C1 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V (190 bytes) @ 0x000000000348e35c [0x000000000348d200+0x115c]
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000001f913800 JavaThread "Thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=23272, stack(0x0000000023db0000,0x0000000023eb0000)]
=>0x000000001f747000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=17172, stack(0x0000000022ae0000,0x0000000022be0000)]
  0x000000001f6e1000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1792, stack(0x0000000020000000,0x0000000020100000)]
  0x000000001f6e0000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=17888, stack(0x000000001ff00000,0x0000000020000000)]
  0x000000001f6da800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21532, stack(0x000000001fe00000,0x000000001ff00000)]
  0x000000001e698800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8208, stack(0x000000001f280000,0x000000001f380000)]
  0x000000001e67f000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19868, stack(0x000000001f180000,0x000000001f280000)]
  0x000000001e67b800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=536, stack(0x000000001f080000,0x000000001f180000)]
  0x000000001e677800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11812, stack(0x000000001ef80000,0x000000001f080000)]
  0x000000001e675000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18244, stack(0x000000001ee80000,0x000000001ef80000)]
  0x000000001e671000 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9464, stack(0x000000001ed80000,0x000000001ee80000)]
  0x000000001e613000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18452, stack(0x000000001ec80000,0x000000001ed80000)]
  0x000000001e612000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=22124, stack(0x000000001eb80000,0x000000001ec80000)]
  0x0000000002e48000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15756, stack(0x000000001ea80000,0x000000001eb80000)]
  0x000000001e5a0800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19316, stack(0x000000001e980000,0x000000001ea80000)]
  0x0000000002d4e800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=13828, stack(0x00000000029d0000,0x0000000002ad0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000001c7ba000 VMThread [stack: 0x000000001e480000,0x000000001e580000] [id=15356]
  0x000000001e733000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001f380000,0x000000001f480000] [id=12816]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

heap address: 0x00000006c2e00000, size: 4050 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x00000007c0000000

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 23141K [0x000000076ba00000, 0x0000000770e80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65024K, 19% used [0x000000076ba00000,0x000000076c61c720,0x000000076f980000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x000000076f980000,0x00000007703fce20,0x0000000770400000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770e80000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 104716K [0x00000006c2e00000, 0x00000006cd780000, 0x000000076ba00000)
  object space 173568K, 60% used [0x00000006c2e00000,0x00000006c94431e8,0x00000006cd780000)
 Metaspace       used 16013K, capacity 17172K, committed 17408K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1943K, capacity 2219K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012210000,0x0000000012a00000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000ebf9000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006b925ce0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000013750000, 0x0000000017698000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000017698000, 0x000000001b5e0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000cf0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=6393Kb max_used=6393Kb free=239367Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002e50000, 0x00000000034a0000, 0x0000000011e50000]
 total_blobs=2256 nmethods=1718 adapters=450
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 9.306 Thread 0x000000001e67f000 1727   !   3       java.awt.EventDispatchThread::pumpOneEventForFilters (190 bytes)
Event: 9.307 Thread 0x000000001e67f000 nmethod 1727 0x000000000348ced0 code [0x000000000348d200, 0x000000000348e988]
Event: 9.314 Thread 0x000000001e67f000 1728       3       java.awt.EventQueue::cacheEQItem (60 bytes)
Event: 9.314 Thread 0x000000001e67f000 nmethod 1728 0x000000000348fa90 code [0x000000000348fc20, 0x0000000003490388]
Event: 9.314 Thread 0x000000001e67f000 1729       3       java.awt.EventDispatchThread$HierarchyEventFilter::acceptEvent (225 bytes)
Event: 9.315 Thread 0x000000001e67f000 nmethod 1729 0x0000000003490590 code [0x00000000034907c0, 0x0000000003491a28]
Event: 9.315 Thread 0x000000001e67f000 1730       3       java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment::isHeadless (4 bytes)
Event: 9.315 Thread 0x000000001e67f000 nmethod 1730 0x0000000003491d50 code [0x0000000003491ee0, 0x0000000003492408]
Event: 9.435 Thread 0x000000001e67f000 1731       3       sun.awt.image.SurfaceManager::getCacheData (20 bytes)
Event: 9.436 Thread 0x000000001e67f000 nmethod 1731 0x0000000003492550 code [0x00000000034926c0, 0x00000000034928a8]

GC Heap History (6 events):
Event: 1.780 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 64968K [0x000000076ba00000, 0x0000000770e80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65024K, 99% used [0x000000076ba00000,0x000000076f972208,0x000000076f980000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770e80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f980000,0x000000076f980000,0x0000000770400000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 0K [0x00000006c2e00000, 0x00000006cd780000, 0x000000076ba00000)
  object space 173568K, 0% used [0x00000006c2e00000,0x00000006c2e00000,0x00000006cd780000)
 Metaspace       used 13491K, capacity 13648K, committed 13824K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1634K, capacity 1713K, committed 1792K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1.789 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 10751K [0x000000076ba00000, 0x0000000770e80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65024K, 0% used [0x000000076ba00000,0x000000076ba00000,0x000000076f980000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x000000076f980000,0x00000007703ffce0,0x0000000770400000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770e80000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 20123K [0x00000006c2e00000, 0x00000006cd780000, 0x000000076ba00000)
  object space 173568K, 11% used [0x00000006c2e00000,0x00000006c41a6fa8,0x00000006cd780000)
 Metaspace       used 13491K, capacity 13648K, committed 13824K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1634K, capacity 1713K, committed 1792K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 4.033 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 75775K [0x000000076ba00000, 0x0000000770e80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65024K, 100% used [0x000000076ba00000,0x000000076f980000,0x000000076f980000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x000000076f980000,0x00000007703ffce0,0x0000000770400000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770e80000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 20123K [0x00000006c2e00000, 0x00000006cd780000, 0x000000076ba00000)
  object space 173568K, 11% used [0x00000006c2e00000,0x00000006c41a6fa8,0x00000006cd780000)
 Metaspace       used 15760K, capacity 16880K, committed 17152K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1925K, capacity 2193K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 4.050 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 10723K [0x000000076ba00000, 0x0000000770e80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65024K, 0% used [0x000000076ba00000,0x000000076ba00000,0x000000076f980000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770e78c58,0x0000000770e80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f980000,0x000000076f980000,0x0000000770400000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 68353K [0x00000006c2e00000, 0x00000006cd780000, 0x000000076ba00000)
  object space 173568K, 39% used [0x00000006c2e00000,0x00000006c70c0688,0x00000006cd780000)
 Metaspace       used 15760K, capacity 16880K, committed 17152K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1925K, capacity 2193K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 7.784 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 75747K [0x000000076ba00000, 0x0000000770e80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65024K, 100% used [0x000000076ba00000,0x000000076f980000,0x000000076f980000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770e78c58,0x0000000770e80000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f980000,0x000000076f980000,0x0000000770400000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 68353K [0x00000006c2e00000, 0x00000006cd780000, 0x000000076ba00000)
  object space 173568K, 39% used [0x00000006c2e00000,0x00000006c70c0708,0x00000006cd780000)
 Metaspace       used 15928K, capacity 17096K, committed 17408K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1940K, capacity 2217K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 7.803 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 10739K [0x000000076ba00000, 0x0000000770e80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65024K, 0% used [0x000000076ba00000,0x000000076ba00000,0x000000076f980000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x000000076f980000,0x00000007703fce20,0x0000000770400000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770400000,0x0000000770e80000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 104716K [0x00000006c2e00000, 0x00000006cd780000, 0x000000076ba00000)
  object space 173568K, 60% used [0x00000006c2e00000,0x00000006c94431e8,0x00000006cd780000)
 Metaspace       used 15928K, capacity 17096K, committed 17408K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1940K, capacity 2217K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 3.919 Thread 0x0000000002d4e800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000032a3f14 method=java.util.LinkedList.node(I)Ljava/util/LinkedList$Node; @ 7
Event: 3.919 Thread 0x0000000002d4e800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000032b8748 method=java.util.LinkedList.node(I)Ljava/util/LinkedList$Node; @ 7
Event: 7.069 Thread 0x0000000002d4e800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000033b62cc method=java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;I)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 2
Event: 7.069 Thread 0x0000000002d4e800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000033b62cc method=java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;I)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 2
Event: 7.069 Thread 0x0000000002d4e800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000033b62cc method=java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;I)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 2
Event: 7.069 Thread 0x0000000002d4e800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000033b62cc method=java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;I)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 2
Event: 7.069 Thread 0x0000000002d4e800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000337e6cc method=java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;I)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 2
Event: 7.069 Thread 0x0000000002d4e800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000335615c method=java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;I)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 2
Event: 7.069 Thread 0x0000000002d4e800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000003396004 method=java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;I)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 2
Event: 7.299 Thread 0x0000000002d4e800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003372b10 method=sun.java2d.loops.Blit.getFromCache(Lsun/java2d/loops/SurfaceType;Lsun/java2d/loops/CompositeType;Lsun/java2d/loops/SurfaceType;)Lsun/java2d/loops/Blit; @ 11

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.808 Thread 0x000000001f913800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x000000076d5556a8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u212\12974\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 0.837 Thread 0x000000001f913800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x000000076d555930) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u212\12974\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 0.868 Thread 0x000000001f913800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x000000076d555bb8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u212\12974\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 0.875 Thread 0x000000001f951000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x000000076d7e01a8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u212\12974\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 710]
Event: 0.898 Thread 0x000000001f913800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x000000076d555e40) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u212\12974\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 0.928 Thread 0x000000001f913800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x000000076d5560c8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u212\12974\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 0.958 Thread 0x000000001f913800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x000000076d556350) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u212\12974\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 0.989 Thread 0x000000001f913800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x000000076d5565d8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u212\12974\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 1.020 Thread 0x000000001f913800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x000000076d556860) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u212\12974\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]
Event: 1.050 Thread 0x000000001f913800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x000000076d556ae8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u212\12974\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1185]

Events (10 events):
Event: 8.232 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 8.232 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 8.232 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 8.232 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 8.232 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 8.232 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 8.232 Executing VM operation: BulkRevokeBias
Event: 8.232 Executing VM operation: BulkRevokeBias done
Event: 9.436 loading class ch/aplu/jgamegrid/GGMouse
Event: 9.436 loading class ch/aplu/jgamegrid/GGMouse done
```

Comment: I have cut down the part after dynamic libraries(the qustion is too long).If you want to see them, please contact me.

Comment: Looks like .jar files on the classpath are overwritten while the application is running.